# Pandas : Multiple rolling means in a single line

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create two new columns of rolling means using groupby. I currently have these two lines that do exactly what I want.

```
data_df['mean_7'] = data_df.groupby('athlete_id')['A'].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(center = False, window = 7, min_periods = 1).mean())
data_df['mean_28'] = data_df.groupby('athlete_id')['A'].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(center = False, window = 28, min_periods = 1).mean())
```

I would like to combine them into a single line. I have got as far as:

```
data_df.groupby('athlete_id')['A'].apply(lambda x : [x.rolling(center = False, window = 7, min_periods = 1).mean(), x.rolling(center = False, window = 28, min_periods = 1).mean()])
```

This is not quite right as I can not find an easy way to have the returned result merge with the original DF (data_df).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of having it in a single line?

You can do:

```
data_df['mean_7'], data_df['mean_28'] = data_df.groupby('athlete_id')['A'].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(center = False, window = 7, min_periods = 1).mean()), data_df.groupby('athlete_id')['A'].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(center = False, window = 28, min_periods = 1).mean())
```

now it is a single line.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was looking for. I was just curious if it would make it faster.